# Hide modal on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, modal-dialog

I have the following function in my website to submit a form thats in a modal. All works fine except when i uncomment that commented line, when I uncomment that line my test mysql insert on page /index.php/trainings/add isn't executed. I'm new to javascript and ajax so I fear I'm missing something stupid. The modal div I want to close is called id="addModal", it tried simply $(div#addModal).hide(); but this only hides the div and leaves the black "matt" background over the webpage.

```
$(function() {  
  $("button#submit_button").click(function() {  
    var date = $("input#date").val();  
    var dataString = 'date='+ date;
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "/index.php/trainings/add",  
        data: dataString,  
        success: function() {  
            //$(div#addModal).modal.hide();
        }  
    });
    return false;
  });  
});
```

would be very gratefull if someone could help.

Thanks,
James

EDIT:

Don't know if this could be of any use but this is my modal with the form in it:

```
<div id="addModal" class="modal hide faid" area-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h3>Add Training</h3>
</div>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="addform">
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Date</label>
            <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
        <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text" id="date"></input>
        <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, don't know if this is revelant but I have JQuery and bootstrap loaded into the page.

Comment: The class for "addModal" should be "modal hide fade" instead of "modal hide faid"?. I am so new to JavaScript that I don't know if that can cause an issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying referencing the modal div itself. And check the bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals) for more

```
$("#addModal").modal('hide');
```

Comment: that hides my modal but doesn't execute the php script :(

Comment: I doubt the modal hiding has anything to do with the php script not executing.

Comment: php script is: /index.php/trainings/add where the post URL goes. Things is if I comment the modal hiding out and leave "success" with a empty function the script is executed. I'll add my form to the original question, see if it helps.

Comment: Copy and past my code in place of what you've commented .. you aren't passing in the div properly .. the ID should be in quotes .. maybe its hitting an error.

Comment: thanks the bloody quotes was it :) Owe you a beer or whatever you drink if your ever over in north italy :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this should work, as long as your div id is "addModal"

```
...
success: function() {  
  $('#addModal').hide();
}  
...
```